# CRM 2011 Advanced Find Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've got an org where every Advanced Find request fails immediately regardless of the entity. I can't find an example of this happening in CRM anywhere else. Has anybody seen this?

The error is:

```
    >MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (FetchXml="<fetch version="1.0"...").

Error Message: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.

Error Details: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (FetchXml="<fetch version="1.0"...").

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: http://crmdev02/xxxxx/AdvancedFind/fetchData.aspx?pagemode=iframe&sitemappath=Workplace%7cMyWork%7cnav_dashboards

Stack Trace Info: [HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (FetchXml="<fetch version="1.0"...").]
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is still an issue but this solution worked for me:

http://www.crmxpress.net/Blog/post/2011/10/22/After-migrating-CRM-40-to-CRM-2011-CRM-is-throwing-an-exception-A-potentially-dangerous-RequestForm-value-was-detected-from-the-client-.aspx